# ttk.Spinbox missing in tkinter.ttk?

Tags: python, tkinter

The tkinter version I am using is accessing tk.TclVersion=8.6.

I am able to access stylename='TSpinbox' from `ttk.Style()`.

```
Stylename = TSpinbox
Layout    = [('Spinbox.field', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'we', 'children': [('null', {'side': 'right', 'sticky': '', 'children': [('Spinbox.uparrow', {'side': 'top', 'sticky': 'e'}), ('Spinbox.downarrow', {'side': 'bottom', 'sticky': 'e'})]}), ('Spinbox.padding', {'sticky': 'nswe', 'children': [('Spinbox.textarea', {'sticky': 'nswe'})]})]})]
Element(s) = ['Spinbox.field', 'null', 'Spinbox.uparrow', 'Spinbox.downarrow', 'Spinbox.padding', 'Spinbox.textarea']
Spinbox.field                  options: ('fieldbackground', 'borderwidth')
null                           options: ()
Spinbox.uparrow                options: ('background', 'relief', 'borderwidth', 'arrowcolor', 'arrowsize')
Spinbox.downarrow              options: ('background', 'relief', 'borderwidth', 'arrowcolor', 'arrowsize')
Spinbox.padding                options: ('padding', 'relief', 'shiftrelief')
Spinbox.textarea               options: ('font', 'width')
```

According to [documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_spinbox.htm), widget `ttk.Spinbox` exists. But in Python 3.6.5 `tkinter.ttk`, such a widget does not exist:

```
AttributeError: module 'tkinter.ttk' has no attribute 'Spinbox'
```

May I know when this widget will be made available or which version of Python `tkinter.ttk` already offers the `ttk.Spinbox` widget? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right, the implementation of the ttk Spinbox was omitted. [This has been solved for python 3.7](https://bugs.python.org/issue32585).

You can copy this implementation to do this yourself though:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Spinbox(ttk.Entry):

    def __init__(self, master=None, **kw):

        ttk.Entry.__init__(self, master, "ttk::spinbox", **kw)
    def set(self, value):
        self.tk.call(self._w, "set", value)

root = tk.Tk()
s = Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=10)
s.set(5)
s.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks. :) It works. I have replaced `ttk.Entry.__init__(self, master, "ttk::spinbox", **kw)` with `super().__init__(master, "ttk::spinbox", **kw)`. I wonder why it isn't appended to python 3.6 `tkinter.ttk`?

Comment: Yeah that works as well, I got the code I posted directly from the [git commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/105fcbfd6a91abea0ecd71e53651f39ad6f6039b) so it works exactly as it would in python 3.7.

Comment: Greatly appreciate the new link as I can also see the options of ttk.Spinbox... :)